# How to select rows from table where group does not contain value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains the following fields:

> Thedate,Thetime,Course,OR,L1R,L2R,L3R

I would like to only return values if a group (Thetime) does not contain the value "0" in L3Ra column.

I have tried the following statement but it only removes those values that contain the "0" where I would like to remove the whole group

```
  SELECT *
FROM orclass t
WHERE t.l3r NOT IN
   (SELECT s.l3r  
    FROM  orclass s
    WHERE s.l3r = '0')
    and Thedate = "2019-01-18"
ORDER BY t.Thetime
```

What i would like to do is remove any groups (Thetime) that contain a "0" in the L3R column.

```
Thetime L1R L2R L3R
  12:00  1     2   1
  12:00  1     2   0
  13:00  1     1   1
  13:00  2     0   8
  14:00  2     4   9
  14:00  0     3   6
```

Would become:

```
Thetime L1R L2R L3R
  13:00  1     1   1
  13:00  2     0   8
  14:00  2     4   9
  14:00  0     3   6
```

because the group 12:00 contains a "0" in LR3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM orclass o
WHERE Thedate = "2019-01-18"
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM  orclass o1
        WHERE o1.Thedate = o.Thedate 
            AND o1.Thetime = o.Thetime 
            AND o1.lr3 = '0'
    )
ORDER BY Thetime;
```

Comment: Worked just perfect - Thanks.

Comment: @JarrattPerkins next time when post a question, you should add data of all columns. In this question, you omitted value of the columns `Thedate` in sample data although you mentioned it in table structure and your query. It made difficult 
 for others to find a good answer for the group of `Thedate` and `Thetime`. And as data of `Course` columns is unknown, maybe you should add `Course` column into my query (same as thedate, thetime) to get the correct result, too.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your first where clause to t.Thetime instead of t.l3r like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM orclass t
WHERE t.Thetime NOT IN
   (SELECT s.Thetime 
    FROM  orclass s
    WHERE s.l3r = '0')
    and Thedate = "2019-01-18"
ORDER BY t.Thetime
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use an `EXISTS` clause to check this:

```
SELECT
    s1.Thetime,
    s1.L1R,
    s1.L2R,
    s1.L3R
FROM orclass s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM orclass s2
                  WHERE s1.Thetime = s2.Thetime AND s2.L3R = 0);
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

use corelated subquery

```
select t1.* from table_name t1 
where  not exists ( select 1 from table_name t2 where t2.Thetime=t1.Thetime
                                and L3R =0)
```

Comment: This isn't the correct logic.  The OP wants to filter out groups _do have_ `L3R=0`.